# Visual Studio 2013 - MSVCR110D.dll missing

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2013

I'm working on a program and it compiles fine, but it gives me a "MSVCR110D.dll is missing.."-error. I run Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7 64bit, I also use boost 1.55.0 and SFML 2.1. Google and a fellow superuser post didn't help me out. I got told to install c++ redistributable  but that didn't help me either. I'm not that good with C++ yet so excuse me if I missed something.

Answer (score 2):

The **D** version is the **Debug** Runtime. `msvcr110` means it needs to C++ 2012 runtime. The file is not redistributable so you need to install `Visual C++ 2012` or the 2012 C++ Express Edition, too. Maybe one of your 3rd party libs depend on this file.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install (or deploy/package) the [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784).

If you're compiling a 32 bit executable (default), you'll need the 32 bit runtime. Similar way you'll need the 64 bit runtime for a 64 bit executable.

Comment: That's not the actual problem. The OP clearly said installing the redistributable package didn't help. In fact, "the debug version of `msvcr100.dll` [is not redistributable and] is named `msvcr100d.dll`." [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa985618.aspx)